# How to give color for listview in android

Tags: java, android, listview

i am having a list view in which i would like to give a background color to a row when it is pressed.When i select an item its changing the color but the problem is when i scroll down other rows too are got colored.I don't want that.

Here is my code:
 Thanks in advance

listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

```
          @Override
          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
              int position, long id) {
              final String item = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position); 
                  Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                  view=parent.getChildAt(position);
                  view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);

          }
          });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should handle that in your adapter. A listview re-uses listelements and in your case the one with green background will be reused when you scroll. Instead you should tell your adapter which item was clicked

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

          @Override
          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
              int position, long id) {
                   ((YourAdpater)listView.getAdapter()).setSelected(position);

          }
          });
```

And in your Adapter's getView() you can then set a background if the current position equals the selected one or not...

Or look at the listview's choice mode http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#attr_android:choiceMode

I'm not really familiar with it, but it might be helpful...

Comment: try google...
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html
 or  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166497/custom-adapter-for-list-view or

http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/09/android-listview-with-adapter-example.html

Answer (score 0):

The nicest way to handle this is to set `listview.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);`, which allows you to select multiple list items.

To highlight the selected items, all you have to do is create a custom background selector, which defines how the items will look like in which state. For your example this would be something like this:

selector.xml:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@android:color/white" android:state_activated="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/green" android:state_activated="true"/>

</selector>
```

Put this file in your drawable folder and give your list items this background like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/selector">

    ... 

 </LinearLayout>
```

This way you don't have to handle clicks on the items.
You can retrieve the selected items via `listview.getCheckedItemPositions()`

Answer (score 0):

To highlight a ListView you dont have to manually colour them, Android already has a function for it.

m_ResultsArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1,m_ResultsArray)

Instead of using a simple_list_item_1 use a simple_list_item_activated_1. This will allow ur list to be highlighted and you can even check which one is checked by using

this.m_ResultsListView.getCheckedItemPosition();

Hopefully this answers your question :>